# Linting errors whenever I use absolute paths

Tags: atom-editor, eslint

I'm getting `unable to resolve path to module` linting errors whenever I use absolute paths. Relative paths working fine.

So if I'm one directory up from root `import '/imports/startup/server';` doesn't lint, but `../imports/startup/server';` will.

Is there some way to force the project to realize the root?

I'm using atom editor, but I'm getting the same errors from the command line:

`error  Unable to resolve path to module 'imports/startup/server'  import/no-unresolved`

Comment: Is your `.eslintrc` file in your project root?

Comment: I've tried both local in project root and global config.  Same result.

Comment: And where are you running the command line from? Within the root directory where the .eslintrc file is located?

Comment: Yes.  In the root of the project.

Comment: When you use absolute paths does your app work? That is, ignoring ESLint, does your app compile/work when you use absolute paths?

Comment: Yes, app works fine, the absolute paths resolve fine, it's just the linting resolver.

Comment: Can you post your entire `.eslintrc` file?

Comment: I'm just extending airbnb: https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/blob/master/linters/.eslintrc

Comment: Are you using React. If so try the adding `ecmaFeatures: {jsx: true}` to your `.eslintrc` file.

Comment: I am using react but AirBnB already adds jsx: https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/blob/master/packages/eslint-config-airbnb/rules/react.js - Why would that effect import/no-unresolved?

Comment: Try to copy/paste the `plugins`, `parserOptions` and `ecmaFeatures` objects from AirBnB to your own `.eslintrc` file.

Comment: Something like this - https://gist.github.com/brettdewoody/e5985dc854f5865ebb4e84355656d494

Comment: Just tried that but no luck.  Tested the file is definitely being read by adding a rule.

Comment: I don't believe extending applies to anything other than rules. So I think you'll need to copy the other settings in the `.eslintrc` file.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help @BrettDeWoody - while talking it through with you I found npm packages that configure the resolver for node, webpack and meteor that did the trick.

Comment: You should answer your own question when you can and accept the answer, seems useful for others.

Answer (score 4):

The resolver can be configured for whichever build system you are using. There are resolvers for:

- Webpack: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-import-resolver-webpack
- Node: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-import-resolver-node
- Meteor: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-import-resolver-meteor

You can then specify that the import/resolver uses these settings in your `.eslintr` file.  For example:

```
"settings": {
  "import/resolver": "meteor"
 }
```

A complete `.eslintr` file might look like this:

```
{
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "rules": {
    "no-extra-parens": 0
  },
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": "meteor"
  }
}
```

*Don't forget to `npm install` all of the airbnb bits if you are extending it.*